# classLList.toggle property not working with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML Code is for navigation bar:

```
<Nav>
    <ul>
      <li onclick="showDropDownMenu('dropdown-menu')" class="dropdown nav-icon">
        <span class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></span> 
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Workout</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="home nav-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li class="active nav-btn"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
      <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">Stay Fit</a></li>
      <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="nav-search">
      <input type="search" name="Search" class="text-area" placeholder="Search...">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-search search-btn"></span>
    </form>
  </Nav>
```

And my css for second ul element

```
nav .dropdown ul{
display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  min-width: 150px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.3s linear;
}

.show{
  display: block;
}
```

My Js code is
**showDropDownMenu.js**

```
function showDropDownMenu(className)
{
  document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].classList.toggle("show");
};
```

And it doesn't work. dropdown doesn't apear at all. I don't know what's going on. Have been looking for the error for a day now.

But if i use the display.block property it works. Js looks like this --

```
function showDropDownMenu(className)
{
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  if(x[0].style.display = "none"){
    x[0].style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
    x[0].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Above works fine but the problem is I have to double click to one every page reload to make the dropdown furst appear.

Comment: Your css is wrong, should be no quotes around block: `display: block;`

Comment: the class `show` is added as `classList.toggle` added `show` to the class name. But it seems `display:none` is already applied to the class. As the class is added on your developer tool :)

Comment: Developer tool can be seen by pushing `F12` or `Shift + Ctrl + i`.

Comment: @Nick I believe my CSS is right. It is written without quotes.

Comment: @jacobkin I am writting code in Sublime Text. Are you talking about browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript code is actually working. But the issue is that your css for `nav .dropdown ul` having `display: none` have more weight than `display: block` of `.show` class when applied. That's why even after the `toggleClass` gets executed, your element is not getting displayd in DOM. Because even after the `display: block` of `show` class is applied, the `dsplay: none` of `nav .dropdown ul` will be the active style, since the class selection have more weight. The best way to fix this out is to make `.show` class more specific. That is instead of `show` use `nav .dropdown ul.show` this will give more priority to `display` property of `show` class when applied.

```js
function showDropDownMenu(className) {
  document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
nav .dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  min-width: 150px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.3s linear;
}

nav .dropdown ul.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li onclick="showDropDownMenu('dropdown-menu')" class="dropdown nav-icon">
      Click Here
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></span>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Workout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="home nav-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i></a></li>
    <li class="active nav-btn"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
    <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">Stay Fit</a></li>
    <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form class="nav-search">
    <input type="search" name="Search" class="text-area" placeholder="Search...">
    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-search search-btn"></span>
  </form>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS code is wrong, is display: block without quotes.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo when i wrote the code on stackoverflow. I wrote it without quotes in actual code.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally accepted as bad practice to use **inline** event listeners in JavaScript or to put **inline** CSS styles directly on an HTML element. Keeping your code separated makes it easier to debug and avoids CSS specificity issues. I'd suggest restructuring your code like this (I added comments where code should be changed):

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <!-- Remove event listener from HTML -->
    <li class="dropdown nav-icon">
      Click Here
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></span>
      <!-- Add 'hide' class to hide dropdown on page load -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu hide">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Workout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="home nav-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i></a></li>
    <li class="active nav-btn"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
    <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">Stay Fit</a></li>
    <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form class="nav-search">
    <input type="search" name="Search" class="text-area" placeholder="Search...">
    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-search search-btn"></span>
  </form>
</nav>
```

```css
nav .dropdown ul {
  /* Remove "display: none" from this selector */
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  min-width: 150px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.3s linear;
}

.show {
  /* Remove quotes around 'block' */
  display: block;
}

/* Create new hide class */
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
function showDropDownMenu(className) {
  var x = document.querySelector(className);
  // Toggle hide and show classes
  if(x.classList.contains('hide')) {
    x.classList.remove('hide')
    x.classList.add('show');
  } else {
    x.classList.remove('show')
    x.classList.add('hide');
  }
}

// Get li.dropdown and add click listener to it
// call showDropDownMenu with the dropdown-menu ul on every click
document.querySelector('.dropdown').addEventListener('click', function() {
  showDropDownMenu('.dropdown-menu');
});
```

This works, while also keeping your code neatly separated. If you're familiar with jQuery, you can dispense altogether with the `.hide` and `.show` classes, since jQuery provides a `toggle()` function that does this automatically for you:

```html
<!-- Add jQuery script to the head of your HTML 
Get jQuery link at https://code.jquery.com/
-->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

```js
// JavaScript file reduced to THREE lines
$('nav ul li.dropdown').click(() => {
  $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
})
```

If you choose the jQuery route, you should remove the `.show` and `.hide` classes from your CSS and HTML, and the `nav .dropdown ul` **would** need to have `display: none` on it:

```css
nav .dropdown ul{
  /* Add display: none back if using jQuery */
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    min-width: 150px;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 1;
    transition: visibility 0.3s linear;
  }
  
  /* .show{
    display: block;
  }

  .hide {
    display: none;
  } */
```

Comment: Thank you man. But I don't understand why it takes double click to show the bar in first reload when i use style.display property.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why that's happening - I'm not able to replicate it; using your original code, the toggle works the first time I click, every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `display:none` inline so the `display` style property returns something:

```js
function showDropDownMenu(className)
{
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  if(x[0].style.display = "none"){
    x[0].style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
    x[0].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
nav .dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  min-width: 150px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.3s linear;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<Nav>
  <ul>
    <li onclick="showDropDownMenu('dropdown-menu')" class="dropdown nav-icon">
      <span class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></span>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Workout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="home nav-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i></a></li>
    <li class="active nav-btn"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
    <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">Stay Fit</a></li>
    <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form class="nav-search">
    <input type="search" name="Search" class="text-area" placeholder="Search...">
    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-search search-btn"></span>
  </form>
</Nav>
```